# Combining relativistic velocities in the same direction using Lorentz transformation matrices

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

It is known that when combining the Lorentz Transforms of two frames with velocities $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ in the same direction it is equivalent of computing a Lorentz Transform of a single frame with velocity $v_{3}$ given by:

$$v_{3}=\frac{v_{1}+v_{2}}{1+\frac{v_{1} v_{2}}{c^{2}}}$$

In order to derive this I took the two matrices corresponding to the Lorentz Transform of the first frame (represented by the matrix $\mathbf{T}_{1}$) and of the second frame (represented by $\mathbf{T}_{2}$) and took the matrix product:

$$\begin{align*}\mathbf{T}_{1}\mathbf{T}_{2}&=\begin{bmatrix}\gamma_{1} & -\beta_{1}\gamma_{1} \\ -\beta_{1}\gamma_{1} & \gamma_{1}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\gamma_{2} & -\beta_{2}\gamma_{2} \\ -\beta_{2}\gamma_{2} & \gamma_{2}\end{bmatrix}\\ &= \begin{bmatrix}(1+\beta_{1}\beta_{2})\gamma_{1}\gamma_{2} & -\gamma_{1}\gamma_{2}(\beta_{1}+\beta_{2})\\ -\gamma_{1}\gamma_{2}(\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}) & (1+\beta_{1}\beta_{2})\gamma_{1}\gamma_{2}\end{bmatrix}\end{align*}$$

I then tried to show that this was equivalent to a Lorentz transformation represented by a matrix $\mathbf{T}_{3}=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\gamma_{3} & -\beta_{3}\gamma_{3} \\ -\beta_{3}\gamma_{3} & \gamma_{3}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, where $\gamma_{3} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta_{3}^{2}}}$ and $\beta_{3}=\frac{v_{3}}{c}$.

However, when equating $\gamma_{3}=(1+\beta_{1}\beta_{2})\gamma_{1}\gamma_{2}$, I end up with:

$$\gamma_{3}=\frac{1+\beta_{1}\beta_{2}}{\sqrt{(1-\beta_{1}^2)(1-\beta_{2}^{2})}}$$

Which doesn't appear to equal the expected result, so I am unsure where my error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error, you just did not carry the calculation out to the end. Remember that what you want to calculate is $v_3$, not $\gamma_3$. You have two expressions for $\gamma_3$, equating them gives

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta_3^2}}=\frac{1+\beta_1\beta_2}{\sqrt{(1-\beta_1^2)(1-\beta_2^2)}}.$$

With $\beta_i=v_i/c$ for $i=1,2,3$, you just have to solve this equation for $v_3$ and end up with your desired expression,

$$v_3=\frac{v_1+v_2}{1+\frac{v_1v_2}{c^2}}.$$